# Laravel Reusable Scope & Eager loading

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, scope, eager-loading

I have three models: Restaurant, FoodItems, Taxes with the following relationships

```
Restaurant belongsToMany FoodItems (vice versa)
FoodItems belongsToMany Taxes (vice versa)
Restaurant hasMany Taxes (Taxes belongsTo Restaurant)
```

I have 2 routes

1. to show list of all menus in that restaurant /restaurant/{restaurantId}/menus
2. to show details of single menu item //restaurant/{restaurantId}/menus/{id}

The MenuController which handles the above is as follows

```
public function index(Restaurant $restaurant, Request $request)
{
    $query = $restaurant->foodItems()->withRestaurantTaxes($restaurant);

    $query->ofCategories($request->get('category'));

    return $query->get();
}

public function show(Restaurant $restaurant, FoodItem $foodItem, Request $request)
{
    $foodItem->load(['taxes' => function ($query) use ($restaurant) {
        $query->ofRestaurant($restaurant->id);
    }]);

    return $foodItem;
}
```

Restaurant Model has the following relation

```
public function foodItems()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(FoodItem::class, 'restaurant_food_items');
}
```

Food Item Model has the following

```
public function taxes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tax::class, 'food_item_taxes');
}

public function scopeWithRestaurantTaxes($query, $restaurant)
{
    return $query->with(['taxes' => function ($query) use ($restaurant) {
        $query->ofRestaurant($restaurant->id);
    }]);
}
```

Tax model has the following

```
public function restaurants()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Restaurant::class);
}

public function scopeOfRestaurant($query, $restaurantId)
{
    return $query->where('restaurant_id', $restaurantId);
}
```

I have 2 issues with my code,

1. In the controller's index method, withRestaurantTaxes() is a scope method that I have created, which is similar to the load constraint on show method. So is there a way to reuse the scope or restructure to avoid duplication.
2. In the controller's index method, the query builder is created from the restaurant model like this **$restaurant->foodItems()->withRestaurantTaxes($restaurant)**, is there any way to avoid passing restaurant again as a parameter to the scope method.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this:

```php
public function scopeWithTaxes($query)
{
    return $query->with(['taxes' => function ($query) {
        $query->ofRestaurant($this->id);
    }]);
}
```

But that will only work as long as you have a `Restaurant` instance.

Comment: Hi sorry, this doesnt work. "$this" is an instance of FoodItem in the scope scopeWithRestaurantTaxes method.